# create RDF statements

Tags: semantics, rdf, jena

is there any tool that can create RDF statements using the resources of ontologies ?

Comment: can you explain a bit what you want to do ? Maybe a use case would help to nderstand your scenario.

Comment: I mean if i have an ontology file can i generate rdf statement from it ; are there any tool do this job ?? for example this owl :<owl:Class rdf:ID="Book">
   <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Product"/>
   <rdfs:label>Book</rdfs:label>
   <rdfs:subClassOf>
     <owl:Restriction>
       <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#writtenBy" />
       <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
     </owl:Restriction>
   </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usual suspects: [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) and the [Manchester OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) or [Rowlex](http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int/) if you're more into Microsofty and .net stuff or even the [Redland](http://librdf.org/) libraries. If you're more into Python, take a look at [RDFLib](http://www.rdflib.net/).

Hope that helps.